# creating objects inside while loops and printing them outside

Tags: java

Edit: 
I if the imput is no, 10 - yes 9. I want the output to be

pipe 1 is 10 diameter

pipe 2 is 9 diameter

:::::::

Sorry in advance if this is a realy stupid question, but I have tried different things and cant get the code to work.

First I tried something like this

```
Pipe (counter) = new Pipe();
```

To be able to call the objects by name later. That did not work, but could have solved the whole problem, and i wouldent have to list my objects.

Then I tried to add

```
     System.out.println(a.getSize);
```

inside the for loop, but since I create the objects inside the while Loop, it wont get them. I thought that was the whole point of listing them, so clearly I am missing something. 
Does anybody have ideas of how I can do this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
int sizeToAdd;
int counter = 0;
int forCounter = 1;
String add = ("no");
List<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();

while (add.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
  System.out.println("is this the last pipe?");
  add = keyboard.nextLine();

  Pipe a = new Pipe();

  System.out.println("what  is the size");
  sizeToAdd = keyboard.nextInt(); 
  keyboard.nextLine();//emty string

  a.settSize(sizeToAdd);
  object.add(a);
  counter++;

}    
for (Object number : object) {
 System.out.println("pipe " +(forCounter)+ (" is ") + (" diameter"));
 forCounter++; 
}

keyboard.close();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Could you maybe edit your question to provide some sample keyboard input and some desired console output?

Comment: Just a helpful hint: be careful about how you name your variables. In a big application with lots of code, having variables named "object" and "number" will get VERY confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a list of Pipes so that your second loop will know how to access the diameter.

```
List<Pipe> object = new ArrayList<Pipe>();
```

Then you can have a loop with Pipe objects:

```
int forCounter = 0;
for (Pipe pipe : object) {
    System.out.println("pipe " +(forCounter)+ (" is ") + pipe.getSize().toString() + (" diameter"));
    forCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry maye Im just slow. but I thought that                   List<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();                                      was a list of all the pipes?

Comment: The difference here is that Java knows and is sure that the list has Pipes in them. This way you can access methods and properties of the pipes in the list.